# Java Stream collected object in List, shows size as 1 but object is null

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I am working on a SpringBoot project, where while testing I was deliberately passing something like this in the request and got a NullPointerException:

```json
{
    "materials": [
        {

        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to use @NotNull on `materials` in the Request Class as the `materials` field can be null.
but when it is not null I want to make sure a few fields are present as based on that I need to validate its value.

```java
final List<Material> materials = materialRequests.getMaterials().stream().map(MaterialRequest::getMaterial).collect(Collectors.toList());

// Throws NullPointerException here
final Set<String> materialIds = materials.stream().map(Material::getUuid).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

While debugging I saw this:

[image]

`materials` shows it has 1 element however it is null, and due to that, I get a null pointer expectation.
How can I put a check here to see whether it is null or not.. and why is the behavior like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out `null` elements from the stream before applying `map()`:

```
final Set<String> materialIds = materials.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Material::getUuid)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.filter()` to filter out null values:

```
final Set<String> materialIds = materials.stream().filter(s -> s != null).map(Material::getUuid).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```